# how to set ranger to be default mode in dired in Doom emacs?

Tags: doom, ranger

I'm new to doom emacs and I like it but I'm still new, so I saw this package called ranger that is a minor mode inside emacs and I want to make it run by default whenever I open dired. The documentation says set this variable `ranger-override-dired-mode t`, but I don't know where to start.

I tried to add this in `~/.doom.d/config.el` but it crashes when launch emacs
can you please guide me !!

Comment: What error message do you get? It is unlikely that setting a variable can do that, so I suspect something else is wrong. Does it work when you don't set the variable?

Comment: when i add this line "(ranger-override-dired-mode t)" it crashes

Comment: @NickD but when i add "(setq ranger-override-dired-mode t)" it doesnt crash but when i open dired i dont get the features of ranger :(

Answer (score 5):

Doom's `:emacs dired` module has a `+ranger` flag. Enable it and run `doom sync` on the command line. i.e. uncomment `:emacs (dired +ranger)` in `~/.doom.d/init.el`.

Then ranger will be the default UI for dired.

---

See [this entry in the manual](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/docs/getting_started.org#modules) for details on what Doom modules (and flags) are.

Comment: this causes dired to start in "Deer" mode NOT "Ranger"